# SQL Query for Left join and Count of Max Value of Top 5

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables as category and task,in category i have 2 fields as catID and catName, and in task i have only 1 field as catID which can be duplicate. what i want is to have a sql query to match the task.catID with category table to get catName, and in return i want to verify the count of that catname in TASK table. i have tried some different queries but can't retrieve the results. queries are as below.

```
SELECT categories.catId, categories.catName, MAX(catName)
FROM tasks
    LEFT JOIN categories ON tasks.catId = categories.catId
WHERE tasks.catId = categories.catId
```

2nd query is

```
SELECT MAX(catId), count(catid) as countof
from tasks
group by catId
ORDER BY `countof` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

my table is like as

```
Category                   task
catID --- catName          catID
1         ABC1              1
2         ABC2              1
3         ABC3              1
4         ABC4              2
5         ABC5              3
6         ABC6              2
7         ABC7              5
8         ABC8              5
```

I WANT TO HAVE THE RESULTS AS BELOW for top 5 count.

```
catName  catName Count
ABC1      3
ABC2      2
ABC5      2
```

any help in this regard would be appreciated. kindly help me to get these results.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (LIMIT is product specific...)

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd query is almost there.  This should give you what you want:

```
select Category.catName, Count(Category.catName) countof
from Task
join Category on Category.catID = Task.catID
group by Category.catID
order by countof desc limit 5
```

Comment: Thanks mate, got the results. appreciated your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

This website always help me a lot to complete my tasks. appreciated response from seniors and experts to help juniors.

```
select categories.catName, Count(categories.catName) countof
from tasks
join categories on categories.catID = tasks.catID
group by categories.catID
order by countof desc limit 5
```